# How to make a dictionary with a 2D Array as Value?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make a dictionary in Swift that looks like this:

```
["key1": [["val1", "val2", "val3"], ["vala", "valb", "valc"]], 
 "key2": [["test1", "test2", "test3"], ["testa", "testb", "testc"]]]
```

Right now, I have this code:

```
var lst1 = ["val1", "val2", "val3"]
var lst2 = ["vala", "valb", "valc"]
var lst3 = ["test1", "test2", "test3"]
var lst4 = ["testa", "testb", "testc"]

var str_to_array: [String: [String]] = [:]
str_to_array["key1"] = lst1
```

It gives me the output I am looking for when I print it, which is

```
["key1": ["val1", "val2", "val3"]]
```

However, when I try to push another list into the dictionary for the same key like this:

```
str_to_array.append(contentsOf: lst2)
```

I get this output:

```
["key1": ["val1", "val2", "val3", "vala", "valb", "valc"]
```

while I am looking for this:

```
["key1": [["val1", "val2", "val3"], ["vala", "valb", "valc"]]
```

`var str_to_array: [String: Array] = [:]` gives me an error, and placing double like this: `var str_to_array [String: [[String]]]` also gives me an error. What should I try now?

Comment: Check the updated answer. It's a single line now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dictionary should have an *array of string arrays* as value.

```
var lst1 = ["val1", "val2", "val3"]
var lst2 = ["vala", "valb", "valc"]
var lst3 = ["test1", "test2", "test3"]
var lst4 = ["testa", "testb", "testc"]

var dict: [String: [[String]]] = [:]
```

To store values, you should have a method which stores the list or appends the list with the existing list(s) if a value already exists.

```
func saveToDictionary(list: [String], withKey key: String) {
    dict[key, default: []].append(list)
}

saveToDictionary(list: lst1, withKey: "key1")
saveToDictionary(list: lst2, withKey: "key1")

print(dict)
```

**Edit:** Improved the answer after referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53428515/7734643).