# Swift - dictionary with array - get reference to array

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I currently have this code:

```
var dic = [String: [String]]() 

if (dic.index(forKey: key) != nil){
    dic[key]?.append(m)
}
else {
    dic[key] = [m]
}
```

However, in `dic.index(forKey: key)` and `dic[key]?.append(m)` I calculate the key twice.

Is there a possibility to do something like this?:

```
var dictKeyVal = &dic[key]
if (dictKeyVal != nil) {
    dictKeyVal?.append(m)
}
else {
    dic[key] = [m]
}
```

where I get the reference to array at key or nil if there is no key

Comment: **Tip:** You should never do this in Swift `if (dictKeyVal != nil)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use a default value for the subscript and your whole code will be simplified to this:

```
var dic = [String: [String]]()
dic[key, default: []].append(m)
```

Comment: Default should be [m]

Comment: @JoakimDanielson nope, that would result in `dic[key] = [m,m]` instead of the desired `dic[key] = [m]` in case there was no value for `key`.

Comment: Sorry, now I get it. Neat solution btw.